# Authorize attribute always redirect to login site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-authorization

I try to create a user page that access would have the only users who are authorized and have a "User" role.
The problem is that always returns 302 status code and redirects to the login page.

Yes, I'm sure that the user has a "User" role - I checked.

The project is in ASP .NET Core MVC 3.1 - Web Application

**UserController**

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "Client")]
public class UserController : Controller
{ 
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options => { 
    options.AddPolicy("Client", policy => 
    policy.RequireRole("User"));
});
```